# Is it a bad idea to name a rails model "Post"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a model to manage blog posts and name it "post."  Could this create a conflict with Rails built in methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Rails Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#avoiding-name-collisions) covers this issue:

> **3.2 Avoiding Name Collisions**
>
> You are not free to use just any name for your associations. Because
>   creating an association adds a method with that name to the model, it
>   is a bad idea to give an association a name that is already used for
>   an instance method of ActiveRecord::Base. The association method would
>   override the base method and break things. For instance, attributes or
>   connection are bad names for associations.

Figuring out whether your model name will cause a collision when it is used in an association is simple:

```
a = MyModel.new
a.respond_to?(:update) # => true
a.respond_to?(:post) # => false (assuming you haven't defined the association yet)
```

Edit:

I should probably point out that associations are not the *only* potential source of name collisions; in your case though it's pretty clear that `update` clashed with the `:update` method in ActiveRecord::Base.

Rails models are constants in the top-level namespace, so watch out for conflicts that arise from including library code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a bad idea to name a rails model “Post”

Yes. Your instincts are correct. Although not a reserved word, POST is a database action. Why not choose a name that has no opportunity to create confusion with the framework: Article, Comment...?